# How can I filter lines of a file with a certain number of characters faster?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

So I have some jacked up flat files that are rather large.

What I'm trying to do, using PowerShell, is to select only the lines that have the expected amount of delimiters and output them to a file.

This works:

```
function fixColDelim([string]$importFile)
{
$goodFile = $importFile.Replace(".txt", "_GOODX1.txt")

$sr = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $importFile
$sw = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $goodFile

$sr.ReadLine() | Out-Null
$sr.ReadLine() | Out-Null

While (-not $sr.EndOfStream) {
    $line = $sr.ReadLine().ToString()
    $gl = ($line.ToCharArray() | Where-Object {$_ -eq '|'} | Measure-Object).Count
    Write-Host $gl
    if($gl -eq 350)
    {
        $sw.WriteLine($sr.ReadLine())
    }
}
$sw.close()
$sr.close()
}
```

However, it's RBAR so it's not the most efficient method against a 500mb file.  Any suggestions?

Zach

Comment: What version of PowerShell do you have? Are you assuming that their are not nested delimiters in your file?

Comment: 351 columns of data... damn

Comment: I'm sure there are, but it's not text qualified so it'd be tough to find them.  It's version 4.

Answer (score 3):

You are already using streams which is great for larger files in general and as a go to for situations like this.

**You are reading the lines twice in each loop!** . This should be making you write the wrong lines to file. Use the variable you stored for the line instead

```
$sw.WriteLine($line)
```

The following line would be a good place to make strides as well.

> ```
> $gl = ($line.ToCharArray() | Where-Object {$_ -eq '|'} | Measure-Object).Count
> ```

There are a few costly operations here. Splitting the line into a char array and `Measure-Object` being the big ones. I will test to see if I can bench mark this but using some regex methods should be faster here

```
$gl = ([regex]::Matches($line,"\|")).count
```

Last thing, if you are comfortable with removing it, is to drop the `Write-Host` line. Writing data to console is also a performance hog.

---

You would have to refactor your code for this and I do not know if it would be faster but you can use `-ReadCount` with `Get-Content` now to pull in large chunks of the files at a time as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here was the alternative with the replace regex.

```
$gl = ($line -replace '[^|]','').length
```

If you might have nested delimiters, you could take this further.

```
$gl = ($line -replace '[^|"]','' -replace '"\|"',"").length
```

Answer (score 2):

So much code to do something so simple. First off take a look at how fast `Select-String` is at handling your file:

```
Select-String $importfile -Pattern '([^|]+\|){350}' | Select line | Set-Content $goodfile
```

If you want something faster try passing a ReadCount to a `Get-Content` which will stream your file in batches. Something like this:

```
Get-Content $importfile -ReadCount 1000 | ? {$_ -match '([^|]+\|){350}'} | Set-Content $goodfile
```

Comment: In my experience `sls` is not as fast as `gc -readcount` or streamreader

Comment: YMMV, `sls` is my choice in most cases.

Comment: Is there away to read to the position of the next crlf (char(13)+char(10)).  the issue is line breaks within a field where the file is not text qualified not nested delims.  So I could kill that crlf, then merge it with the subsequent line(s) and recheck the bar count.

Comment: This regex pattern won't work if a line contains empty fields between delimiters (and the obvious alternative `([^|]*\|){350}` will incur terrible backtracking)